# C/C++ time_t in microseconds

Tags: c++, c, seconds, time-t

This program returns the time in seconds. I need to return it in **microseconds**.

```cpp
time_t timeStart = time(0);
usleep(2.5e6);
time_t timeEnd = time(0);

float R = (timeEnd - timeStart);
std::cout << R << std::endl;
```

Comment: Uh, multiply by a million?

Comment: I guess he meant with the precision

Comment: The question is clearly about C++, not C.

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for a higher resolution, you can use [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) from C++11.

```
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;

high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

/* some extensive action... */
usleep(2.5e6);

high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);

std::cout << "It took me " << time_span.count() << " seconds.";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Outputs something like

```
It took me 0.091001 seconds.
```

Example from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now/

Comment: thanks very much, but I have a problem with my compilator (Kate+Terminal). I need c++11.

Comment: @Strife I suppose you're using GCC/Clang. You'll probably want to add `-std=c++0x` to the build options to enable C++11 support.

Comment: For the Windows platform, you should avoid using ``std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`` with VS 2012/2013 due to a [known issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/719443/) and use ``QueryPerformanceCounter`` instead. This is fixed with VS 2015.

Comment: Lukas, please remove the last s in the first line of code, it should end with std::chrono.
Apart from that: thanks!
ps. if you'd add #include <chrono> I think it would be more complete, but that's maybe just personal.

Comment: You can use `auto` instead of explicitly declaring the types.

Answer (score 3):

using function gettimeofday

```cpp
#include <sys/time.h>

int gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz);
int settimeofday(const struct timeval *tv, const struct timezone *tz);
```

Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):

```cpp
settimeofday(): _BSD_SOURCE
```

**Description**

The  functions  `gettimeofday()`  and  `settimeofday()`  can  get and set the time as well as a timezone.  The tv argument is a
`struct timeval` (as specified in ):

```cpp
struct timeval {
    time_t      tv_sec;     /* seconds */
    suseconds_t tv_usec;    /* microseconds */
};
```

and gives the number of seconds and microseconds since the Epoch (see time(2)).  The tz argument is a `struct timezone`:

```cpp
struct timezone {
    int tz_minuteswest;     /* minutes west of Greenwich */
    int tz_dsttime;         /* type of DST correction */
};
```

this function can get microsecond

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [`std::chrono`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono) header. It contains many different options for time manipulation, including the ability to convert to [`microseconds`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) via [`std::chrono::duration_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast).